# Black screen on windows logon

Tags: java, screenshot, awtrobot

We're currently developing an application to control classrooms. We already know about iTalc but it won't work for us since its development is quite stuck. We feel more comfortable writing in Java rather than in c++, so we decided to create our own in Java.

For now most things are working but we got a problem with the screen capturing when on WINLOGON.

Our application uses Robot for screen capturing (we display up to 50 remote screenshots in main frame) and VNC to provide us real time remote control.

Everything works fine while the application is run as logged user, but if we wrap it in a service to start our application during winlogon credentials we get BLACK SCREENSHOTS.

After reading we learnt about the Windows Session Isolation 0 since windows vista, but since iTalc does, there's sure to be a workaround we can't seem to find in the iTalc code.

The main question is: Has anyone solved the session isolation 0 with Robot class? Also being able to tell robot to switch which session we want him to take screenshot from would be great.

Comment: No, there is no direct way of using the Robot class in the session 0 isolation case. I don't believe the support is there in java to connect to different sessions for the GUI case, which is what would be needed to get it to work properly. From what I understand of iTalc, it uses Terminal Services.

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar, but in c#.  As long as you can make the win32 API calls from java it should work.

You'll need a separate application to actually take the screenshot and that app is started from the service while impersonating the logged in user.

Here is our C# code:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095509/125406